# Unique data no longer unique after .append()

Tags: python

**Edited** The example is now fully reproduce-able.

I'm stuck on a problem I shouldn't be stuck on, using a familiar pattern. I generate some random data, prove to myself that it is randomized by printing three *distinct* rows, append that randomized data to a list, and whoa - the rows in the resulting list are all identical.

```
from random import randint

fields = [
    {"foo": "bar"},
]


def some_randomizing_func(adict):
    adict["number"] = randint(0, 1000)
    return adict


rows = []
for ith in range(3):
    row = [some_randomizing_func(field) for field in fields]
    print("BEFORE ", row)  # Proves they are unique at this point
    rows.append(row)  # Therefore each list in this list should also be unique

print("AFTER ", rows)  # But they're not!
```

Running this as a script gives:

```
BEFORE  [{'foo': 'bar', 'number': 306}]
BEFORE  [{'foo': 'bar', 'number': 943}]
BEFORE  [{'foo': 'bar', 'number': 230}]

AFTER  [
    [{'foo': 'bar', 'number': 230}],
    [{'foo': 'bar', 'number': 230}],
    [{'foo': 'bar', 'number': 230}]
]
```

I have tried everything I can think of - using a dictionary with numbered keys instead of a list, using `fields.copy()`, using `enumerate()` with a counter and assigning to the list index, but the problem persists. How can it be possible that `row` proves itself unique during the first `print()` but is no longer unique by the second `print()`, after being appended?

**Update:** It can be fixed by changing the append() line to

`rows.append(copy.deepcopy(row))`

but I don't understand *why* this fixes it, and it feels like it's working around the actual problem.

Comment: Does it work with `row.append(copy.deepcopy(row))`?

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds like your code doesn't actually work like the pseudocode you've posted. It sounds like you're repeatedly appending the same list object to `rows` instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: That said, we can't really tell what's going on, because you haven't posted a [mcve]. We can guess, and we've got some good guessers here, but we're not supposed to have to guess.

Comment: @Rightleg That's it! That worked, thanks much. Post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it accepted. Can't believe I didn't try that. Cheers!

Comment: @shacker You need to improve the question. Just because you've got the answer you want, doesn't mean it will help anyone else. Currently we don't know *why* `deepcopy` fixes your problem. There are already answers which involve `deepcopy` as a solution to a clear and specific problem. If you formulate your question well, you will find out it's a duplicate.

Comment: @shacker I posted my answer. But keep in mind that this is not an actual solution, but more of a hint to understand this behaviour.

Comment: @PeterWood I tried to formulate my answer so that `deepcopy` does not look like the right way, but rather a clue, or a tool to debug. What do you think about it?

Comment: To the downvoters: This is not pseudocode, it's real code with the name of the randomizing function renamed. It would take too much code to show everything it does because the data structures are complex, but that's not important. My understanding at this point is that the solution works because the original list comprehension is saved in memory and then reassigned to each iteration during the  append, but perhaps someone can explain it better.

Comment: @shacker That does not have to do with the comprehension: try with `[i for i in range(0, 10, ith+1)]` instead and you'll see that it works as expected. I'm pretty sure the issue is in `some_randomizing_func`.

Comment: @shacker We all work on complicated code that is too much to post. The best way to deal with this is to test you assumptions. Write a new little piece of code. Learn to break down problems into small parts. As @user2357112 suggested, read about how to create a [mcve]. It will make you a better programmer, better able to solve your own problems, to find existing solutions, and, if you're still stuck, help you explain precisely what you don't understand. Your current understanding of why the solution works is wrong, so you haven't learned anything. You're (likely) modifying and reusing `field`.

Comment: Apologies. Last night I was stressed and exhausted. Yes, I should have boiled it down to a simpler, reproduce-able case. I have now done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your function `some_randomizing_func` function has some kind of side effect, that has every list it returns actually point to the same list object.
This is what you should investigate.

However, as a quickfix, you can use `copy.deepcopy` to have an independent copy of `row`, which will make it safe from any side effect.

```
import copy

rows = []
for ith in range(3):
    row = [some_randomizing_func(field) for field in fields]
    print("BEFORE ", row)
    rows.append(copy.deepcopy(row))

print("AFTER ", rows)
```

Note that a deep copy's drawback is that it increases the RAM consumption.
You probably can find a better way to fix this.

Comment: Thanks @rightleg - I think you're right that this could be fixed in the randomizing function, but it's not clear where. It takes a dictionary, adds a new key to it with a randomized value specific to a given datatype, and returns the modified dictionary. Not sure what to change there. Thanks much, I've banged my head on this way too long.

Comment: This really just hides the problem, though. It's very likely that the bug in `some_randomizing_func` is going to cause other problems, and it may be corrupting the `fields` list or other data structures.

Comment: @shacker: "It takes a dictionary, adds a new key to it with a randomized value specific to a given datatype, and returns the modified dictionary" - yup, that would cause the problem. You're reusing the same dictionary objects, not creating new dictionaries, and you're definitely corrupting the `fields` list's contents.

Comment: @user2357112 @rightleg I have now provided a fully reproduce-able example in the original question. While I see that it can be "fixed" with `deepcopy()` I still do not see where the code is going wrong. It is still the case that the first print() shows it doing the right thing, but something is doing wrong while appending, and I don't understand why.

Comment: @shacker It's because you're always appending to `rows` a list that consists of the `field` dictionary. In other words, the `row` that you append to `rows` is a different object at every iteration, but all these objects contain a reference to the same object, which you mutate at every iteration. So after the loop, while the rows are all different objects, they all contain the same object.

Comment: "So after the loop, while the rows are all different objects, they all contain the same object." This is the key. Thanks a bunch @Rightleg. I've posted an answer that fixes it without resorting to `deepcopy()`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from @rightleg and others, this is the key takeaway:

"So after the loop, while the rows are all different objects, they all contain the *same* object." Therefore, the problem can be fixed without `deepcopy()` by making a copy of the dictionary in the randomizing function:

```
def some_randomizing_func(somedict):
    newdict = somedict.copy()
    newdict["number"] = randint(0, 1000)
    return newdict
```